# Why can't it resolve the domain name?

Tags: systemd, wireguard

Here is part of the Wireguard systemd service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for %I
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
PartOf=wg-quick.target
```

As you can see, it should run wireguard once the network is online.

Nevertheless, some times at the boot, the service fails because of this error:

> Name or service not known: `mydomain.ddns.net:51820'

My conf file has `Endpoint = mydomain.ddns.net:51820`.

How can I prevent that?

I could potentially modify the `wg-quick@.service` to add a timeout and retries but I don't think it's the best solution.

Needless to say if I start the service manually, it works. The problem isn't the DNS or the domain, the problem is the service being run before it's able to do the dns request.

- AlmaLinux 8.8

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.123.1
nameserver 192.168.111.1
```

Comment: would the answer in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/867830/systemd-start-service-only-after-dns-is-available) be suitable

Comment: I see there is no other solution than modifying the service file... thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure about that, I just found that question to see if it helps

Comment: understood, thanks. And this solution actually doesn't work because my service is parameterized, a timeout would be better.

Comment: What is your OS? Do you have maybe a `systemd-resolved` service enabled? Can you share the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file?

Comment: I use RHEL8.8, `systemd-resolved` is disabled. Why does it still work 9/10 times without it?

Comment: There are some networking issues with RHEL 8.8, can you find yours there? (I didn't look in deeply) https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.8_release_notes/known-issues#known-issues-networking

Comment: I'm using a gigabit connection, unlikely to be that. Thanks!